# Django View issue-ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm running into trouble with related model classes.
I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Cine(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    ciudad = models.ForeignKey(Ciudad, db_column='ciudad')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    ...

class Funcion(models.Model):
    idpelicula = models.ForeignKey(Pelicula, db_column='idpelicula')
    idcine = models.ForeignKey(Cine, db_column='idcine', null=True)
    hora = models.TimeField(null=True)
    ...
```

My views looks like this:

```
def FuncionesByCine(request, id):
    funcionesByCine = Funcion.objects.filter(idcine=id)
    context = {'funcionesByCine': funcionesByCine}
    return render_to_response('funciones-by-cine.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def CineDetail(request, cineslug):
    cine = Cine.objects.get(slug=cineslug)
    context = {'cine': cine}
    return render_to_response('cine-individual.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And the url's:

```
#Queryset containing all the Cine objects
cine_info = {
    'queryset': Cine.objects.all(),
    'template_name': 'cines-all.html',
}


url(r'^complejos/$', list_detail.object_list, cine_info),
url(r'^complejos/(?P<cineslug>.*)/$', views.CineDetail),
url(r'^complejos/(?P<cineslug>.*)/funciones/(?P<id>.*)/$', views.FuncionesByCine),
url(r'^funciones/$', views.FuncionesAll),
url(r'^funciones/(?P<id>.*)/$', views.FuncionesByCine),
```

This gives me the desired 'funciones' associated to a 'cine' from Funcion when I call it from the url like this: localhost:8000/funciones/1.

Now, what I want to be able to do is to call this view from a template that displays the individual movie theater('cine') and with this view to be able to displays all the showtimes('funciones') that are on that 'cine'.

I'm trying to use the same view but a different url:

```
url(r'^complejos/(?P<cineslug>.*)/funciones/(?P<id>.*)/$', views.FuncionesByCine),
```

And the template calling looks like this:

```
{% extends 'cines-menu.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    <div class="cine">
        <p>Nombre: <a href="funciones/{{cine.id}}">{{cine}}</a></p>
        <p>Ciudad:{{cine.ciudad}}</p>
        <p>Direccion:{{cine.direccion}}</p>
    {% endblock %}
```

This is currently not working. Any ideas?
Thanks!

edit: I have added the other views and urls(also the one that use cineslug)

Comment: Hi, first you should do better regex on your urls. Assuming the id is a numeric field you should be matching every single value. 

So, start by instead of (?P<id>.*) replace it by (?P<id>\d+). 
The same for the slug field. instead of (?P<cineslug>.*) replace for something more related with a slug field. (?P<cineslug>[\w-]+).

Comment: @andrefsp Thanks for the tip, I don't have much experience with regex but i will google the ones that you gave me to understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what specifically is not working? what errors are you receiving?

I see one that you're attempting to pass `cineslug` to your view function and as a parameter.

When you used [named groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) they are passed as positional arguments to the view.

`def FuncionesByCine(request, id):`

shoudl be

`def FuncionesByCine(request, cineslug, id):`

but i do believe this will break your original url,

you could change your function definition to `def FuncionesByCine(request, cineslug, id):`

and pass in default value for `cineslug`

`url(r'^funciones/(?P<id>.*)/$', views.FuncionesByCine, {'cineslug': None})`

```
def FuncionesByCine(request, cineslug, id):
  if cineslug is None:
     # this is from funciones/{id}
```

You can retrieve `Funcion`'s by slug like:

`funciones = Funcion.objects.filter(idcine__slug={{ your slug value here }})`

Comment: Hi, actually I dont need cineslug for that view, I just use it in the previous view, the one that has the list of cines that takes me to the individual cine. but in this case, when you click on a cine I want to be able to get the 'funciones' that have that cine as their foreignKey.

Comment: @Edu added example of how to query for `Funcion` by slug

Comment: yes, just tested both and it works by either id, or querying **Funcion** by slug like you mentioned. My confusion was actually with the urls, but I was able to figure out what I was doing wrong.Thanks for your help.